# URLs with queries in <loc> tag, sitemap index file

Tags: php, xml, .htaccess, seo, sitemap

Is that allowed to specify `?id=1` part of URL in **sitemap_index.xml**, `<loc>` tag?

I want to create a dynamic sitemap.

I enabled php executing in .xml files by adding this line `AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml` to .htaccess, and now I want to create one static sitemap index file and one dynamic sitemap file, here is the code I wrote:

**sitemap_index.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://example.com/sitemap.xml?id=1</loc>
      <lastmod>2014-07-06</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://example.com/sitemap.xml?id=2</loc>
      <lastmod>2014-07-06</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://example.com/sitemap.xml?id=3</loc>
      <lastmod>2014-07-06</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   <!-- ..And so on -->
</sitemapindex>
```

**sitemap.xml:**

```
<?php

(empty($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] = 0 : settype($_GET['id'], 'int');

$result = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';

$from = $_GET['id']*45000;
$to = $_GET['id']*45000+45000;

for ($i = $from; $i < $to; $i++) {
  $result .= '
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/page.php?id=' . $i . '</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-07-06</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
  </url>';
}

$result .= "\n</urlset>";

echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: For dynamic XML production, use an XML library - that's better than just concatenating strings (examples already exists here on site IIRC). additionally, which part of the sitemap XML reference documentation is unclear to you about the query parameter you raise in your question?

Comment: @hakre Unfortunately, there is nothing in sitemap XML reference about `?SOMETHING=SOMETHING` part in sitemap index file :c

Comment: Well, those query strings are just a standard part of a HTTP URL, and those are used there. There is nothing wrong with that. Even though the reference does not say which standard to follow for URLs, however actually there is only one, so I won't worry much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Yes. Any valid url can be in a sitemap. A url with a querystring, which is what your example shows, is common and normal and is typically found in all but the most basic site's sitemap.</s>

Yes. You can have sitemap urls with querystrings. [It seems any valid url will work] (.https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49589/sitemap-xml-file-extension-does-it-have-to-be-xml) . Try submitting your url to Google Webmaster Tools and you can verify it works.

Comment: he was asking about sitemap index files, those are not containing URLs to actual pages but to more sitemap files. So the question was more not what URL can be in a sitemap but which URLs sitemaps (the XML files) can have.